# How to track QML particle death

Tags: qml, particle-system

I want to do something with JavaScript when the QML particle dies.

I use the following to check particle death but it's not stable:

```
onAffectParticles: {
    for(const particle of particles) {
        if(particle.lifeLeft() < 0.02) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not stable" mean?

Comment: Sometimes it's can work but sometimes it's can't